I try to create a table using spring jpa and spring jdbc
I did every thing, but there is always an exception:
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceExceptionmore details about the error
I tried to see what's happened in the background through /h2-console but there isn't any table created with the name of entity class.
And I thought it may be helpful to add a new property to see the events more detail but it wasn't helpful:
"spring.jpa.show-sql=true"

application.properties
Dependencies
and the entity class with the getters and setters

Please provide details about the exception and your code in the question, not hidden behind links. Any question (or answer) should be usable even when all the links are dead, which they eventually will be.

It says syntax error, could you please explain a bit more about what query you are trying and possibly write your code here to understand it in a better way?
